# Part P required? Changing Fixed Oven wiring to 13A FCU (UK)

Tags: uk, building-regulations

I can't work out whether or not the following needs an electrician who can provide a Part P certificate under the 2005 Building Regulations (either by installing or approving).

I've got a 32A circuit to a fixed-connection oven that's broken (it's in a "special location", the kitchen). I've got a new oven with a 13A plug (and flex). What I'd like doing is replacing the fixed connection with a 13A fused FCU, to chop off the plug and wire it in.  I'd be confident doing this but don't know if I'd need it done by an electrician or checked by one.

I know there's exceptions for wiring an oven in the regs but can't work out if this is covered. The "special location" stuff is also confusing me.

The oven's "installers" cheekily suggested I (but not they) just put the 13A flex into the fixed, fuseless connection unit but it's unfused back to the consumer unit where it's 32A and I'd rather not burn my house down or invalidate my insurance.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing this is off-topic as a location-specific code question, but let's see what the pros say. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I had thought about taking it to Law but the chances of anyone knowing anything there would be about zero. So I guess there isn't really a StackExchange site for this kind of question.

Comment: You may be right. But, you might still get a reasonable answer; it would help if you added some more info (e.g. what's a "part P fella/gal"?).

Comment: Ok, I'll update that.

Comment: Do you think I should take it to law @DanielGriscom with that update? Maybe I'll wait to see if it's closed here for being off-topic and if so try it there. I assume posting stuff in two different sites at the same time is frowned upon?

Comment: ... I'm just a bit worried about explaining what an FCUs and the like are to a group more used to answering questions about brexit, impeachment, and gun control. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your updates; this seems like the best site for your question, but it still may not be on topic. Again, let's see if any of the pros weigh in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since April 2013 a kitchen has **not** been a **special location** under the amended Part P of the Building Regulations.

> Under the new, revised regulations, electrical work undertaken in
>   kitchens such as adding a new socket or work outdoors such as
>   installing a new security light will no longer be notifiable unless a
>   new circuit is required.

https://www.niceic.com/Niceic.com/media/Schemes/NICEIC-Part-P-Updated-Factsheet.pdf

The work should still be done in compliance with the IET Wiring Regulations, but need not be notified to Building Control.

What you, or the person doing the work should do, ideally, is carry out basic testing on the circuit (polarity, earthing) and make out a Minor Works Certificate accordingly. Templates of MWCs are available free online, but to do the testing in strict compliance with the Regs would require a calibrated tester.

Comment: And questions on "National building codes (of any country)" are on-topic according to the Tour.